# Enabling Replay mechanism with camel from messages from DB

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

Iam trying to implement replay mechanisam with camel ie., i will have to retrieve all the messages already persisted and forward to appropriate camel route to reprocess.This will be triggred by quartz scheduler.

I achieved the same by using below.

1) once the quartz scheduler is triggered, fwd to processor which will query db and have the message as list and set the same in camel exchange properties as list.
2) Use the camel  in which LoopProcessor will set appropriate xml in the iteration in the exchange.
3) fwd it to activemq which will be forwarded to appropriate camel route to reprocess.
Every thing is fine.
I see the following TWO issues
a) there might be 'n' number of msges(10,000+) which will be available in the camel exchange properties in the form of List - i can remove the message which is sent for processing but i think this will do more good on performance and memory usage.

b) I don want to forward all the 10,000+ messages to activemq which i guess will make it exhaustive. Is there a better mechanism to forward 10000+ messages to activemq.
  -- I am thinking to use SEDA/VM(using different camel contexts).how good this can give me considering above questions.

Thanks.

Regards
Senthil Kumar Sekar

Answer (score 0):

If the number of messages is a problem, then not all messages should be loaded at once.

Process as follows (see also my answer for your other [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515018/fetch-specific-set-of-records-for-each-poll-without-setting-the-flag-in-camel?lq=1)):

1. Limit the number of results when querying the DB.
2. Set a marker (e.g. `processedFlag`) for the DB entries that are processed
3. Begin at 1. and query only the not already processed entries until all records are processed.

However, you should test the ActiveMQ approach as well, if 10,000+ messages are really a problem or not.