# fetch specific set of records for each poll without setting the flag in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I need to pick all the messages from db and send it for reprocessing.

my main requirement is

1. i should fetch only certain number of records for each poll and not all the records.
2. next poll should get me next set of records and set it for processing.
3. i should not use processedFlag column in the table - this is not allowed.

I am free to use any camel component such as jpa, sql , jdbc etc.,

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code, please. And yes, use a processed flag if this isn't just a university exercise.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use a "processedFlag" column? Seems really weird as that would surely be the simplest solution.

Comment: I shld have a scheduler which has to pick all the messages and send it for processing.if i use, the processedFlag, then the query will be something like select obj from SomeClass where obj.processedFlag='N' and after picking the messages, i will update the processedFlag to 'Y'.Now, when the second trigger occurs the same query will not pick any data as the flag is already set to 'Y'.
What should i do in this case. Should i have another job to set the flag='N' before the first job is executed.what if my first job(1st scheduler) which will be in progress and the 2nd triggr scheduled gets triggrd

Comment: Initially, do not set obj.processedFlag and test for 'obj.processedFlag is not null'

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Batch Consumer as described here - https://camel.apache.org/batch-consumer.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding a trigger variable such as `processedFlag` is definitely the simplest way to go. Initially this variable is set to `null`.

Procedure:

1. Select all records where `obj.processedFlag is not null`.
2. Process the record.
3. After processing, set `obj.processedFlag` to a value ≠ `null`.
4. Begin at 1.

Not using a trigger variable would only produce a fair amount of headaches, I guess.