# camel throttle doesn't work as expected

Tags: apache-camel

My understanding from the documentation is throttle will pump only messages in certainCount.

eg : 
       
       
            select * from SomeTable
        
       
       
         10

The query will give me 1000 records. my understanding is "someBean" will receive only 10 records(messages) for every 5 seconds.

Isnt that the case?
If no how do i get prescribed count of records for certain interval?

Comment: Would help to see some code...

Comment: <from ...>
<setBody>
  <constant> select * from sometable</constant>
</setBody>
<to uri="jdbc:oracleDatasource" />
<process ref="someProcess" />

<throttle timePeriodMillis="5000">
  <constant>10</constant>
  <to uri="bean:someBean" />
</throttle>


someBean is always fetching all the records at one stretch from the table and doesnt  get 10 records for every 5 second. is it not the behaviour of throttle?

Comment: you need to use the splitter if you want to process the SQL result one row at a time

Comment: Yep am currently working on that.Can you please clarify how throttle works? Does it not pump specific no. of messages for seconds we provide? above has the detailed camel route.but doesnt work that way. would be helpful if its clarified.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in your other SOs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515018/fetch-specific-set-of-records-for-each-poll-without-setting-the-flag-in-camel) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479005/enabling-replay-mechanism-with-camel-from-messages-from-db), you should definitely use process flags for your needs. And have a look at [Spring batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/) which can be used together with Camel too, see [here](https://camel.apache.org/springbatch.html).